# Remove cookie method doesn't work when I have a % symbol in cookie value

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

We have a cookie called gstid which holds a value `"hh%d@gmail.com"`

```
$.removeCookie('gstid', {
    path: '/'
});
```

Interestingly remove cookie returns `false` when there is a `%` symbol in my cookie value. But for all other cookie values it returns `true`. 
Any thoughts on why it goes wrong with a `%`? How do I handle this scenario for a `%`?

You could set a cookie using any plugin and place this snippet on a chrome console.

Thanks in advance.